# loading my sql query result to a combobox

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Im sendin my query to a combobox. when i click that combobox there is an item with a duplicate. I need to remove that duplicate

```
 Try

        dbase.Open()
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, dbase)

        'Read Database
        Dim R As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While R.Read


            frmAdvicing.cmbcourse.Items.Add(R(0))
    End While
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query with `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove the duplicates.

You can also use [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove duplicates in your collection.

Comment: Use Group By rather than Distinct.